# Can we restrict some websites to open in web view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I want in my app to not to open some particular sites in web view. So can we restrict any website in such a way. I want to add one more thing that i want to completely restrict a website not any particular page.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can block the page from loading in this UIWebview delegate method.
Remember to set the class as the webviews delegate. `webView.delegate = self;`, and the class needs to be `UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>`

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if ([request.URL.absoluteString rangeOfString:@"google"].length != 0) {
        // maybe show a UIAlertView to indicate the page is blocked?
        return NO;  
    }else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

EDIT: now it checks if google is mentioned in the URL, and blocks it if it contains Google

Comment: This will load only a particular url suppose google, www.gogle.com, it will be blocked but what about other url's of google.i want to completely restrict google not a particular page.

Answer (score 0):

A little improvement : save the websites you want to block in a NSArray :

```
NSArray *restrictedSites = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://www.google.com", @"http://www.google.co.uk", nil];
```

Now check if the website requested is one of the restricted websites :

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString *site = request.URL.absoluteString

    for(NSString *str in restrictedSites)
    {
        if ([site isEqualToString:str]) 
        {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Alternatively you can check if the website requested contains a URL. In th following case, all the url containing "http://www.google" or "http://www.apple" will be blocked :

First create the restricted site array :

```
NSArray *restrictedSites = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://www.google", @"http://www.apple", nil];
```

Now check if the website requested contains one of the restricted websites (without .com or .co.uk etc...) :

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString *site = request.URL.absoluteString

    for(NSString *str in restrictedSites)
    {
        if ([site rangeOfString:str].location != NSNotFound) 
        {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

So here, all http://www.google.com, http://www.google.fr, http://www.google.co.uk will be blocked.